# Any other better leather conditioner alternatives?

Tags: home, clothing

Would Cocoa Butter vitamin E skin cream be a good leather boot conditioner?

Ingredients are purified water, mineral oil, Cetearyl alcohol petrolatum glyceryl stearate beeswax, polysorbate 60 sorbitan stearate methylparaben propyl para ban vitamin e disodium EDTA cocoa butter.

Answer (score 1):

The following can also be other substitutes:

- Beeswax-solid: Used for protection of leather. It creates a barrier for environmental influences
- Coconut butter-semi solid: It conditions the leather surface.
- Sweet Almond oil-liquid: Softens the leather internally and replaces the natural oils lost through dying
- Castor oil-liquid: This is heavier oil that provides the 'shine'. This could be replaced with mineral oil if necessary.

Comment: What household things you might use actually tend to dry the leather too much, i.e. should I use an ammonia spray to clean dirt?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Nikwax](https://www.nikwax.com/en-gb/), rubbed in thinly using a cloth and left in a warm place.